# Объединение нескольких QBitArray

Tags: qt, qt4

Имеется несколько битовых массивов. Нужно объединить их в один, т.е. в новом массиве сначала должен идти первый, за ним второй и т.д. Единственным решением в голову пришло только вот такое (для примера объединяю два массива):

```
// arr1 - 10101
// arr2 - 10
QBitArray res(arr1.size()+arr2.size());

qint32 count1 = arr1.size();

for (qint32 i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++)
    res.setBit(i,arr1.at(i));

for (qint32 j = count1; j < arr2.size(); j++)
    res.setBit(j,arr2.at(j-count1));

//res - 1010110
```

Есть ли более удачный и правильный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Для сокращения кода можете сделать так:

```
// arr1 - 10101
// arr2 - 10
QBitArray res(arr1.size() + arr2.size()); // res - 0000000
res |= arr1; // res - 1010100

// Дальше не придумал как упростить, оставляю ваше (немного модифицировал):
for (qint32 sz = arr1.size(), i = sz; i < res.size(); i++)
    res.setBit(i, arr2[i-sz]);
```